# Count total number of element which has duplicated in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I would like to ask how to count the total number of elements which has duplicated in Python?

For example

Input: [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]

Output: 2 (because there is 2 elements are duplicated 2 and 4)

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question

Comment: `len(arr) - len(set(arr))`.There should have many duplicates question on Stack Overflow.Have you did some search?

Comment: Do you want the number of elements that _are_ duplicates, or elements that _have_ duplicates? I.e. would the expected result for `[x, x, x]` be `1` or `2`?

Comment: Another that does it: `sum(np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)[1] > 1)`. Anyways, personally I prefer the one provided by @jizhihaoSAMA

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear whether you want the number of elements that *have* duplicates, or elements that *are* duplicates. If you want the elements that are duplicates of others, you can just convert to `set` and get the difference, as suggested in comments. (I added another `4` to the `lst` to illustrate the difference.)

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> len(lst) - len(set(lst))
3
```

However, I think you want the number of elements that *have* duplicates, and that is a little more involved. You can just `count` how often each unique element appears, but that will have complexity O(n²). That's okay for short lists, but not good for lists with thousands of elements.

```
>>> sum(1 for x in set(lst) if lst.count(x) > 1)
2
```

Instead, I'd suggest using `collections.Counter` (or just a `dict` and a `for` loop) to count how often each element appears, then get those with a count > 1 in O(n).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> sum(1 for x in c if c[x] > 1)
2
```

If the elements in the list are sorted, you could also use `itertools.groupby` in O(n), but I'd still prefer the more explicit `Counter`.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sum(1 for k, g in groupby(lst) if len(list(g)) > 1)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all duplicates in one list, remove the duplicates from the new list, and get the length.

```
l = [1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7]

m = set([x for x in l if l.count(x) >1])
print(len(m))
```